# Google Drive API Files.list(maxResults=xxx) strange behaviour

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am trying to get all files from a drive using files.list(). By default the maxResults parameter is 100 by page. To speed up the job I am trying to increase this maxResults up to 1000 (the maximum value as the documentation says). But it still returns me 100 results.

I supposed it was the parameter that wasen't used by the query so I tried a lower than 100 value (eg: 50) and it return me the 50 results.

My question is, is it possible go upper than 100 results by page or not?

Need to mention that, I use the API in python with service account. For the credentials I use SignedJwtAssertionCredentials with a sub parameter to access the drive i want to list.

Here is an extract of my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import httplib2

from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
from apiclient.discovery import build


with open('My\\path\\to\\key') as f:
    dico_account = json.load(f)

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    dico_account['client_email'],
    dico_account['private_key'],
    scope=('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',),
    sub='johnsmith@mydomain.fr')

http = httplib2.Http(proxy_info=httplib2.ProxyInfo(httplib2.socks.PROXY_TYPE_HTTP,
                                                   'myproxydomain',
                                                   3030,
                                                   proxy_user='proxyuser',
                                                   proxy_pass='proxypass'))
credentials.get_access_token(http)

credentials.authorize(http)

drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

filesAPI = drive_service.files()

result = filesAPI.list(maxResults=50, q='\'johnsmith@mydomain.fr\' in owners', fields='items(id,title,parents(id),permissions(role,emailAddress,id,type)),nextPageToken').execute()

print len(result['items'])

result = filesAPI.list(maxResults=500, q='\'johnsmith@mydomain.fr\' in owners', fields='items(id,title,parents(id),permissions(role,emailAddress,id,type)),nextPageToken').execute()

print len(result['items'])
```

It's printing

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
50
100
>>>
```

Comment: it should work.  Please add your code so we can check it.

Comment: without the query, do you still get the same amount of files?

Comment: Yes, I tried without the q parameter and i still get 100 results.